# Are the words "coincident" and "simultaneous" considered synonymous? Else, please explain the difference

Tags: terminology, relativity

In discussions, experimental and thought-experimental descriptions (especially concerning the Theory of Relativity) the words "coincident" and "simultaneous" appear, notably for instance in the foundational literature as:

> [*All our well-substantiated space-time propositions amount to the determination of space-time coincidences [such as] encounters between two or more recognizable material points*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundation_of_the_Generalised_Theory_of_Relativity#ch.3.p.776).

and

> [*We thus require a definition of simultaneity such that this definition supplies us with the method by means of which, in the present case, he can decide by experiment whether or not both the lightning strokes occurred simultaneously.*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics)

Are these two words (at least for these purposes) considered to be synonymous; referring to the very same notion?

Or else: Please clarify the difference between the corresponding two distinct notions.

Comment: This probably should be on English.SE

Comment: @santiago: "_This probably should be on English.SE_" -- Arguably it should. There's a difficulty, though: These two words might be considered and used as good as synonymous when discussing Relativity, while perhaps referring to distinct notions only in some other context(s). I wouldn't quite trust the good contributors at English.SE to understand and appreciate the difference ... (In fact, I wouldn't care much about any context other than Relativity.) p.s. The first example quote actually gives an instance of using "coincidence", rather than "coincident". I'll try to find a more fitting quote.

Comment: that seems fair enough

Comment: Definitely a good fit here since language usage varies considerably with context. Physics in particular requires unusually precise control of language, so the question is appropriate for an expert level physics site.

Comment: BTW, "coincident" and "simultaneous" are adjectives, not adverbs.

Comment: @Duck Joe: "_BTW, "coincident" and "simultaneous" are adjectives, not adverbs._" -- Thanks!, I already made corrections. (I first went to check that "coincident" is not possibly a noun, either, as I had mistakenly assumed while writing the first version of this question.)

Answer (score 1):

"Coincident" is defined in the Google online dictionary as (1) "occurring together in space OR time" (emphasis mine), and (2) "in agreement or harmony".

"Simultaneous" is defined in the same dictionary as "occurring, operating, or done at the same time".  (This begs the question: "Whose time?")  Unfortunately, this dictionary lists "coincident" as a synonym of "simultaneous".  I do not think this is a precise synonym.  It should be avoided.

Used in the context of relativity, "coincident" might be considered a way of describing events which may or may not exhibit simultaneity.

The two examples of usage that you show in your question, illustrate this difference in meaning.  A coincidence includes simultaneity, but may also include an event that is not simultaneous.

Comment: Ernie: "_[...] in the context of relativity, "coincident" may be considered an absolute way of describing two events [...]_" -- Well (+1 for effort), but I find this/your formulation incorrect and unacceptable. No: in relativity, "coincident" means pertaining to exactly only **one event** (several participants "meeting/passing" each other; several observations being made "together, at once"). "_reconciles events occurring in more than one inertial frame of reference._" -- Even **one event** bundles/contains/reconciles "_occurences_" of several participants who aren't at rest to each other.

Comment: @user12262, I've tried to change the answer to be more precise and to conform to a proper relativistic formulation, as you correctly point out.

Comment: I still have to agree with 12262, the only usage of "coincidence" I've ever seen in relativity is to refer to a singular spacetime coordinate. A single event. Multiple things are coincident if at the same spacetime coordinate. They must coincide at the same event. This means simultaneity is necessary as is spatial colocation.

Comment: Ernie: "_"coincident" may be considered an absolute way of describing an event [...]_" -- I appreciate that your edit took accout of my previous comment. "_[...] an event that is not simultaneous._" -- This characterization I find utterly puzzling ... (I just submitted an answer myself; as I had intended from the start. Perhaps it can further clarify my objection to your use and formulation concerning the word "simultaneous", in Relativity.)

Comment: ACuriousJim: I'm afraid I'm trying to re-define "coincident" with meaning that is not there.  I'm trying to encompass more than one reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Relativty, the adjective "coincident" characterizes all that which belongs together ("at once") to only one event without any temporal or spatial or light-like separation; i.e. indications (of any participant at this one event) or occurences (as far as they are understood to be contained within this one event).

In contrast, the adjective "simultaneous" characterizes (possible) pairwise relations between suitable elements (indications, occurances) of certain (necessarily space-like) separate events.

Taken together, Einstein's statements quoted in the OP imply that the notion of "simultaneity" must be defined in terms of determinations of (or conditions on) of who or what had been coincident, or not been coincident.

Accordingly, the words "coincident" and "simultaneous" should denote strictly distinct notions. The occasional use (e.g. in the foundational literature, especially in some of Einstein's own writings) of the word "simultaneous" where the word "coincident" is fitting instead seems due to negligence.